# How to start Hashicorp Vault in docker with existing secret

Tags: docker, hashicorp-vault

I'm building docker compose environment for Spring Boot microservices and Hashicorp Vault. By using `docker compose up` I would like to spin up fully configured development environment with known Vault root token and existing secrets.

Here is my current configuration for vault service

```
  vault:
    image: "vault"
    ports:
      - "8200:8200"
    expose:
      - "8200"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/config:/vault/config
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    environment:
      - "VAULT_DEV_LISTEN_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0:8200"
    #entrypoint: vault server --config /vault/config/vault.json
    entrypoint: vault server --dev --dev-root-token-id="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
```

What is the best way to include prepacked KV secrets in this configuration?

Comment: I don't think you can pre-populate Vault. You'd need the root key first, then use the API with a token to write secrets... Perhaps you can use a separate init container with the Vault CLI? But that would need a way to first securely know the Vault API token...

Answer (score 1):

I achieved that by using the Vault REST API, I setup another service with a  alpine/curl(This one specifically because it is very light weight and has curl preinstalled) image that executes a curl command within a .sh file as soon as the vault image spins up.

**docker-compose.yaml:**

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  vault-service:
    container_name: vault
    image: vault
    ports:
      - "8200:8200"
    environment:
      VAULT_DEV_ROOT_TOKEN_ID: "myroot"
      VAULT_ADDR: "http://127.0.0.1:8200"
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    networks:
      - default

  vault-prepopulate:
    image: alpine/curl
    depends_on:
      - vault-service
    volumes:
      - ./prepopulate_vault.sh:/usr/local/bin/prepopulate_vault.sh
    command: ["sh", "-c", "/usr/local/bin/prepopulate_vault.sh"]
    networks:
      - default

networks:
  default:
    name: vaultnetwork
    driver: bridge
```

Within the .sh file I made it sleep for 5 seconds because I was running into an issue with the curl command executing before vault had properly started. Within the header, the same Vault token that is set in the Docker-Compose file is specified, the data is then set. The last line there is a url, in which the docker bridge network is used as the domain name, the reason for that being that in the docker-compose file both services were configured to use that to allow communication between them, after the "data/" you can configure the path of the secret. More information about the Vault REST API can be found [here](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials/getting-started/getting-started-apis#accessing-secrets-via-the-rest-apis).

**prepopulate_vault.sh:**

```
sleep 5 &&
curl \
    --header "X-Vault-Token: myroot" \
    --request POST \
    --data '{ "data": {"pass": "my-password", "username":"my-username"} }' \
    http://vaultnetwork:8200/v1/secret/data/my-project
```